# Vuex state object length not reactive on computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex

I'm trying to get the length of state object from a computed property but it seems to be not reactive.

the state structure:

```
state: {
   user: {
      cards: {},
   }
}
```

the getter in my store:

```
cardCount(state) {
   return Object.keys(state.user.cards).length
}
```

and a computed prop:

```
calcLeft() {
  return this.$store.getters.cardsLeft - this.$store.getters.cardCount
}
```

on state.user.cards change, i expect from cardCount to return a different value to the computed prop, but that's not happening, it's just stay the same.

Comment: How are you changing `state.user.cards`? If you're adding properties then [the usual caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) apply.

Comment: I'm using mutations, for example to add a new card i will use push to user.cards, my output will be: {1:{name:'foo'}}

Comment: What do you mean by `push`? `cards` is not an array, it doesn't have a `push` method. Using a `mutation` won't help if you're violating the change detection caveats that I linked to. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: sorry, this is not what i meant, what iv'e trying to say is that i used:
obj[key] = somevalue - to add items to user.cards (and not array.push) - after i followed your caveats iv'e realized that this is the wrong way! will need to use Vue.set/delete to do that to make it reactive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [skirtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583563/skirtle), iv'e followed the [the usual caveats](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules) (vuex),

to change a state prop can be done by the following syntax **but it won't be reactive**:

```
state.obj[key] = somevalue
```

to do that we can use both **Vue way** or **spread syntax** to achieve reactivity:

the Vue way:

```
Vue.set(state.obj, key, value)
```

or the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like that:

```
state.obj = {...state.obj, key: value}
```